Alternative proof of the Strong Law of Large Numbers

Wikipedia states that the Three Series Theorem together with Kronecker's Lemma can yield an alternative proof of the Strong Law of Large Numbers. I belive a proof like this must  first use the Three Series Theorem to prove $\sum (X_k-\mathbb{E}[X_k])/k$ converges a.e. and therefore, we may conclude by Kronecker that $\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\mathbb{E}[X_k])/n\rightarrow 0$ a.e. and we are done. It then suffices to prove that  $Y_k=(X_k-\mathbb{E}[X_k]) 1_{|X_k-\mathbb{E}[X_k]|\leq k}$ satisfies properties from $i$ to $iii$ below.
I am having trouble with $iii$.

Here are proofs of i) and ii) and thoughts on iii):

$i)$ $\sum \mathbb{P}(|Y_k|/k>1)<\infty$.

This is easy using Tonelli for the counting measure and the hypothesis for the Strong Law of Large Numbers which implies that $X_1\in L^1$.
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(|Y_k|/k>1)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=k}^\infty \mathbb{P}(j+1\geq|Y_k|>j)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty j\mathbb{P}(j+1\geq|Y_k|>j)=$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty j\mathbb{P}(j+1\geq|X_1-\mathbb{E}[X_1]|>j)\leq \mathbb{E}[2|X_1|]<\infty$$

$ii)$ $\sum \text{Var}[Y_k/k]$ converges.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \text{Var} [Y_k/k]\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2} \int Y_k^2d\mathbb{P}=$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_\mathbb{R}  1_{(0,Y_k^2(w))}(u) dud\mathbb{P}(w)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\int \int  1_{(0,\infty)}(u) 1_{(u,\infty)}(Y_k^2(w))  d\mathbb{P}(w)du=$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}[Y_k^2>u]du=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\int_0^\infty 2u\mathbb{P}(|Y_k|\geq u)du$$
This last step follows from a change of variables. Remembering that $|Y_k|\leq k$ yields that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \text{Var} [Y_k/k]\leq \int_0^\infty \sum_{k\geq u}^\infty\frac{2}{k^2}u \mathbb{P}(|Y_k|\geq u)du \leq$$
$$\int_0^2 4\frac{\pi^2}{6} \mathbb{P}(|Y_k|\geq u)du+\int_2^\infty \int_{u-1}^\infty\frac{2}{s^2}ds u \mathbb{P}(|Y_k|\geq u)du\leq$$
$$ \frac{2\pi^2\mathbb{E}[2|X_1|]}{3}+ \int_2^\infty \frac{4u}{u-1}  \mathbb{P}(|Y_k|\geq u)\leq  \left(2\frac{\pi^2}{3}+8\right)\mathbb{E}[2|X_1|]<\infty$$
This last inequality follows from $u/(u-1)=1+1/(u-1)\leq 2$ for $u\geq 2$

$iii)$ $\sum \mathbb{E}[Y_k/k]$ converges.

I tried estimating $\sum \mathbb{E}[|Y_k|/k]$  just as in $ii)$ but we have a $\sum 1/n$ which diverges, so this isn't promissing. Maybe we need to argue without the modulus.
In this case, let $B_k=\{|X_k-\mathbb{E}[X_k]\leq k|\}$.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y_k]}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\left(\int X_k{1}_{B_k}d\mathbb{P}-\mathbb{E}[X_k]\mathbb{P}(B_k)\right)=$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}\mathbb{E}[X_k]\mathbb{P}(B_k^C)-\frac{1}{k}\int_{B_k^C} X_kd\mathbb{P}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n-\frac{1}{k}\int_{B_k^C} X_k-\mathbb{E}[X_k]d\mathbb{P}$$
This seems promissing as $\sum_k\mathbb{P}(B_k^C)<\infty$ by part i) and $X_k$ must not escape $\mathbb{E}[X_k]$ very much. However, I haven't been able to bound this further.
